# How to get salesforce standart objects using API

Tags: apex, metadata, tooling-api, wsc, tooling

I'm trying to get all salesforce system objects such as `Set, List, System` and their methods. I used tooling api, namely `SymbolTable` class to get methods and variables of specified classes, but i can't find the way how to get system objects. Please, let me know if there is a way how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you tyring to make IDE or Something? Recent update of Force.com IDE does the job of fetching the SymbolTable for you. You can refer its code on Github . Hope that helps,

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE

Comment: @susanoo Yes,  I am making IDE. I'm trying to make autocompletion, so I need some system objects. SymbolTable doesn't contain system objects, such as 'Set, Map' and their methods.

Comment: Force.com provides auto completion for system class like String. I tried api v35 ide and it worked with auto completion like a charm.

Comment: A friend of mine made auto Complete ide plug in for Eclipse, it supports set list and maps. APEX EDITOR Ls is its name.  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/apex-editor-ls

Comment: @susanoochidori Thank you for your advice, but i'm developing my own autocompletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present Apex code or apex APIs do not support real introspection and there is no way to extract list of Standard objects/methods/signatures/properties in an automated way like you can do with real programming languages.

Besides, if you are building an `IDE like` product (and thinking about list of suggestions for auto-completion) you will also want to provide some documentation alongside method/property signature, which you would not get even if introspection was supported.

I do not know this for certain, but can guess, that all existing force.com `IDE like` tools use static (hand made) maps of class/method/doc. 
e.g. Mavens Mate [completions.json](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/blob/master/lib/apex/completions.json)

You could attempt to extract relevant information from [Apex Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_System.htm).
Unfortunately existing apex code documentation is not ideally structured (for automated parsing). With automated parsing you have to either do a lot of manual post processing or add lots of exceptions to your parser. After that, with each new SFDC release your parser may need to be updated to handle changes to internal documentation structure. Sometimes those (doc structure) changes are small, sometimes not so small. Good news (for IDE author) is that Apex does not change very much.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that i will parse methods from Apex Documentation and use it for my autocompletion. As i understood for now there is no way to get standart objects using API.